# Delete Uploaded file in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with an MVC5 project, I have created a simple system that the user can upload a file "CV" for each Employee.
Now all thing work for me fine except "DELETING File".
I need to add action method for deleting uploaded file and the ability to replace it with another file.

in the model class I have created two property HttpPostedFileBase CV to save the uploaded file
and String cvName, to save the file name and use it to create a link to that file.

In the controller that what I have done:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteCV(string cvName)
{
    //Session["DeleteSuccess"] = "No";
    var CVName = "";
    CVName = cvName;
    string fullPath = Request.MapPath("~/Content/CVs/" + CVName);

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
        //Session["DeleteSuccess"] = "Yes";
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

and this is the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CV, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @{
            if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Content/CVs/"
             + Html.DisplayFor(model => model.cvName))))
            {
                <a href="~/Content/CVs/@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.cvName)"> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.cvName)  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.cvName)</a>
                <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteCV", new { @Model.cvName })">
                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Delete.jpg")" width="20" height="20" class="img-rounded" />
                </a>
            }
            else
            {
                <input type="file" name="file" accept="pdf" />
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't delete the file, each time this message appears

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /DeleteCV

Comment: So, what is the question? Your code seems to be OK. What isn't working? What kind of error messages are you getting (if any)?

Comment: Just a couple of notes: surely this should be using the DELETE verb? change it to use HttpDelete to keep the semantics in check. Also, what is the issue you are having? can you post the error?

Comment: @iwayneo uhm, no, you can't send DELETE from a form. And don't call me Shirley.

Comment: @Vilx sorry I just update the Question any help please thanks,

Comment: so this is using a HREF (GET) to call a POST action on a controller? Just use JQuery and be done with it. Then you CAN DELETE ;)

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks for your replay , what I should do?

Comment: Ooh, a delete hyperlink! [I like that!](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The_Spider_of_Doom) :D

Comment: ooofffffff @vilx !! yeah - maybe change the link to a submit!

Comment: There will be good answers for this pretty soon. I'll just add a small tip'n'trick - There's no need to go `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.cvName)` when it's basically the equivalent for `@Model.cvName`. Unless you have some fancy string displayer?

Comment: Another thing I noticed: `<a href="~/Content/CVs/@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.cvName)>` - the syntax with the `~/` is not understood by your browser. That's an ASP.NET internal thing. You need to change this to a proper URL first. I'd do this: `<a href="@Url.Content("~/Content/CVs/"+Model.cvName)">`.

Comment: I don't think the chap deserved a down vote for this q!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're sending a `GET` to a `POST`

Change the `[HttpPost]` to `[HttpGet]`

Or use JQuery and send a `DELETE` verb like I mentioned in the comments

Comment: thanks alot, but when I tried to do that I got this problem,, The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.,,,

Comment: because you have ValidateAntiForgeryToken on a GET - you need to decide what you're doing here. ValidateAntiForgeryToken is for validating antu CSRF tokens in a HTTP POST

Comment: @Tuta - Remove `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`. That only applies to submitting forms, not plain links.

Comment: If you are set on doing this with a GET then remove ValidateAntiForgeryToken

Answer (score 1):

You're using an `<a href="@Url.Action("DeleteCV", new { @Model.cvName })"></a>`, so your link will become `/Controller/DeleteCV?cvName=SomeName`, which will be executed as GET. You don't want that for many reasons, and frankly, the rest of the code is a mess too. Don't do business logic (like checking for a file) in your view, and you might want to add a few checks around that `File.Delete()`.

Do the file check in your controller, saving the result in a model variable, and create a separate form to POST to your Delete method:

```
if (@Model.FileExists)
{
    @using(Html.BeginForm("Cv", "DeleteCV", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.cvName)
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
    }
}
else
{
    @using(Html.BeginForm("Cv", "UploadCV", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="file" name="file" accept="pdf" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    }
}
```